# Результат билда Release не видит libcurlnet

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

Для работы с FTP использую libcurl.dll (+нэтовская обвязка из LibCurlNet и LibCurlShim)

Разработка велась успешно и все функции реализованы, но это на конфигурации Debug
При попытке зарелизится всё успешно забилдилось, но при обращении к библиотеке libcurl получаю следующее:
Unable to load DLL 'libcurl.dll': Не найдена указанная процедура. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)

Где может быть проблема?

Comment: Посмотрите зависимости для `libcurl.dll` каким-нибудь DependencyWalker. Скорее всего что из-за разных путей Debug/Release не находит нужных библиотек.

Comment: @alexolut в смысле? разные пути, но разве здесь какие-то другие механизмы задействованы? walker'ом прошелся - и там и там чего-то не хватает - API..., EXT.... Накачал библиотек, которые вроде нормально выглядят - dcomp, gpsvc,IESHIMS - они красным подсвечивались. закинул в папку с Release - ноль результата

Comment: про пути я имею ввиду, что не очень понимаю - там используются абсолютные пути к библиотекам?

Comment: добавлял в свойствах проекта References Path genb к библиотекам - опять же ничего

Comment: @alexolut где можно почитать про эти пути? В DependencyWalker установлена зависимость только к MSCOREE.DLL (и уже от него дальнейшие зависимости) - он даже не отображает ссылки на библиотеки, которые подключены к нему в проекте VisualStudio

Comment: Всевозможные пути, по идее, прописаны в свойствах проекта. Хотя, я честно говоря, уже сомневаюсь, что для рантайма они будут актуальны. Посмотрите вот [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586(VS.85).aspx#standard_search_order_for_desktop_applications) про порядок поиска dll.

Comment: Еще есть мысль, что `Не найдена указанная процедура` возникает из-за того, что в либе просто нет функции, которая хочет загрузиться в Release. Условно, для Debug/Release выполняется `GetProcAddress` для разных имен.

Comment: @alexolut извиняюсь, но опять не всё понял. кофигурации Debug/Release особо не отличаются - библиотеки все положены рядом, ехе-шник должен их подхватывать хотя бы из рабочего каталога. И интерпретация ошибки при выполнении в другом модуле - Unable to load DLL 'libcurl.dll': Не найден указанный модуль.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена.
[libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/dotnet/) качался вместе и с исходниками и с готовыми либами. Сначала были взяты либы из архива, а позже перекомпилированные. Поскольку в проекте они были добавлены со свойством копирования как "Copy if newer", то в Debug и лежали оригинальные версии. В Release же попались уже "свеженькие", перекомпилированные.
После нового скачивания архива и взятия из него оргинальных DLL, конфиг Release тоже заработал

Comment: Пометьте свой ответ как верный (галочка рядом с ответом).